# How to replace a letter in a string with its corresponding number?

Tags: python

I use Python 3, and I was wondering how you would replace a single letter with its corresponding position in the alphabet. The function should disregard any characters that aren't English letters.

So, for the input:

```
def replaceWithNumber("hello")
```

The function would return:

```
"8 5 12 12 15"
```

For:

```
def replaceWithNumber("Hissy93")
```

The output is:

```
"12 9 19 19"
```

I don't this specific question has been asked before, and was wondering what is the quickest way to do this?

Comment: What is the desired output for `replaceWithNumber("Hi :-)")`?

Comment: Hi Kevin, I forgot to mention that the function should disregard those characters and not return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def replace_with_number (word):
    return ' '.join(str(ord(x) - 96) for x in word.lower() if 'a' <= x <= 'z')
```

Use case:

```
>>> replace_with_number('Hello, World!')
'8 5 12 12 15 23 15 18 12 4'
>>> replace_with_number('StackOverflow')
'19 20 1 3 11 15 22 5 18 6 12 15 23'
```

Comment: Thank you, works really well!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def replace_with_number(str):
...     return [ord(x) - ord('a') + 1 for x in str]
... 
>>> replace_with_number(str)
[8, 5, 12, 12, 15]
>>>
```

Comment: This should return a string, not an array.

Comment: Yep, my bad. But there's already an answer so I'm not editing.